# v-for - looping out basic numbers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a figure under data called pageCount, it's just a number.

I'm trying to output a button for each page, with the number of the loop, but the following fails "use of undefined constant n"

```
<button v-for="(n, i) in pageCount">{{ n }}</button>
```

Why?

Comment: [It should work](https://jsfiddle.net/5e1nzh9j/) - check the value of `pageCount`.

Comment: Is pageCount an array? Or just a number?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, please double check the value of pageCount. Here is a working example using latest Vue.js version:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    pageCount: 10
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-for="(n, i) in pageCount">{{ n }}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you declare the pageCount in the on data key
    //HTML
    
        {{ n }}

```
//Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#root", 
        data: {
            pageCount : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        }


    })
</script>
```

Comment: pageCount is a single figure, e.g. 10

Comment: If the data type of pageCount is an integer (pageCount : 1), it will surely fail it can not loop over an integer so change the data type to array (pageCount : [1])

Comment: Vue can handle numbers as ranges - [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e1nzh9j/).

Comment: Oh sorry about that, using pageCount:10 seems to work for me

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you're using v-for for if pageCount is an integer, if you just want the pageCount then you'd just do:

```
<button>{{ pageCount }}</button>
```

Comment: Vue can handle numbers as ranges - [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e1nzh9j/).